# count number of elements in each pyspark Dstream

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, dstream

I'm looking to find a way to **count the number of elements (or number of RDDs) which I receive each time in my Dstream created in pyspark**, that I'm using. if you know a way that could help me, I will be pleased.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code below, to do give each data a one and then count those ones; **just like a simple word count but instead of words, I count each data.**

I do that with the code below, but if you guys have any other solution feel free to add; Thanks.

```py
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

# Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc = SparkContext('local[2]', 'Networkcount')
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

# Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:7777
data_received = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 7776)

lines = data_received.map(lambda data: 1)
count = lines.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
count.pprint()
```